# Scrolling JFrame for Game in Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, thread-sleep

How can I make a scrolling JFrame? like this code is not scrolling up. So after some time button is vanished. So how Can I make this? Can anyone help me?

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;

class c extends JFrame implements Runnable{ 

    JButton b1;
    c(){        
        b1=new JButton("Going Up");
        b1.setBounds(150,600,100,50);
        this.add(b1);

        this.setSize(400,800);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            while(true)
            {
                b1.setLocation(b1.getX(),b1.getY()-2);
                Thread.sleep(20);   
            }


            }
        catch(Exception ex){
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        c a1 = new c();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(a1);     
        t1.start(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `So after some time button is vanished` - the y value becomes negative. Just add an if statement and reset the value to 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you want scrolling to happen you need to use a JScrollPane.

When you use a scroll pane the scrollbars will automatically occur when the preferred size of the panel added to the scroll pane is greater than the size of the scroll pane.

So this means that every time you try to make the button location a negative value you need to reset the button location to 0, and increase the preferred size of the panel.

You can use the [Drag Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/) as it will automatically recalculate the preferred size of a panel when a component is moved in the panel.

So the basic logic would be something like:

```
JButton button = new JButton("...");
button.setLocation(150, 600);

JPanel panel = new JPanel( new DragLayout() );
panel.add( button );

this.add( new JScrollPane( panel ) );
```

Then in the Thread you need to use:

```
b1.setLocation(b1.getX(),b1.getY()-2);
panel.revalidate();
```

The revalidate() is necessary to invoke the layout manager.

Edit:

This approach only works if there are other components fixed in the panel. With a single component it will always be visible at the top of the frame, but scrollbars will never appear because the preferred size is basically just the size of the single button.